# Reversed Mirror Column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column of data coded with 1s and 0s. Is there a way to create a column that reverses the coding? So that if A3= 1, B3 would be 0. Or is this something I need to go through and do manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well if its a number then this formula:

```
=(A1-1)*-1
```

will work.  If they are string "0" and "1"s, then this:

```
=IF(A1="0","1","0")
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
=ABS(A3-1)
```

(and adjust the "A3" address accordingly for each row, of course).